# Automatically update request Authorization Bearer

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, request, bearer-token

I am trying to make a small webscraping tool that automatically searches for an ad throughout the day/week. After changing the way the information is obtained multiple times throughout the project I have ended up with the following implementation using json.

```
import requests
import json

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.5 Safari/605.1.15",
    "Authorization": "Bearer 419f6f1ff8c97bd9bba241775e5c13a7c66e4203"
}

api = "https://api.blocket.se/search_bff/v1/content?cb=40&cbl1=6&cchb=1&ccsc=1&cg=1020&lim=40&mye=2017&mys=2013&page=0&sort=date&st=s&include=all&gl=3&include=extend_with_shipping"

response = requests.get(api, headers=headers).json()
```

The problem that I have is that the *Authorization Bearer* is found by manually using the safari *Show Web Inspector* however the bearer changes over time and this method can therefore not be used for automatically searching for the ad. How can I find the Bearer automatically using python?

Comment: have you tried using `requests.Session`?

Comment: @MZ I have not, as you can tell I just got into using webscarping and APIs. I tried an example code and got a html file where i could find the * bearerToken*. Is that the string that I am looking for?